# How do I construct a MySQL query with String and DateTime column constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

My Table

[image]

```
Item - State  - Time
C1     Start    7/11/2016 17:04
C1     Passed   7/11/2016 17:39
C2     Passed   7/13/2016 20:28
C3     Passed   7/8/2016 20:53
C4     Start    7/7/2016 17:15
C4     Passed   7/8/2016 17:18
C5     Start    7/18/2016 20:32
C5     Passed   7/18/2016 22:28
C6     Start    7/6/2016 19:13
C6     Passed   7/7/2016 20:23
```

I would like to fetch data from the above table with the following conditions;

```
Select Item 
from Table 
where (      (State = 'Start' and Time <= 17:00) 
         and (State = 'Passed' and Time <= 21:00)
      )
```

I dont want any item doesn't have both Start and Passed.

Can anyone help me, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your query should be easy **depending on your structure**.  You haven't actually shown us the structure - what is the field type for `time`?  Is it varchar? datetime? Something else?  (It does NOT look like it's datetime, and this is an important detail)

Comment: to add to that, your datetime is indeed not in the format of MySQL, is this created by your code and injected? If so, you should indeed consider using a proper datetime object and store it as a datetime in the database, also, why not create two tables, from seeing this i would suggest creating a table with passed records and 'Start' records (to be started more likely)

Comment: SHow us your schema for this table

Comment: Please skip the format of Time. It should be like 2016-07-11 17:39:13. I have wrongly edited in excel with 7/11/2016 17:04. Sorry.

Comment: I have already used Inner Join to fetch the above pasted Table. In that I want to filter further with (State = 'Start' and Time <= 17:00) and (State = 'Passed' and Time <= 21:00).

Comment: 2 questions
1) I dont want any item doesn't have both Start and Passed - What is the logic to determine what record to choose if it has both
2) you grouped the state with a time period.  Looks like that should be an or

Comment: why people cannot just post the expected results? (This happens so often) . It will go a long way in filling the dots. And whats with the double negatives in : " I dont want any item doesn't have both Start and Passed". Did you mean to say: " I want only those items that have both the start and passed" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ITEM FROM *table* a
left join *table* b
ON a.Item = b.item
WHERE a.State = 'Start'
AND b.State = 'Passed'
AND a.Time <= 17:00
AND b.time <= 21:00
```

Comment: Look closer Nick. Accuracy is prefereable to speed. You dont want to start life with a downvote

Comment: Nope, still no good.  The `time` field ALSO has a date in it, and does NOT look like a `datetime` format....

Comment: But I do agree with cale_b and the time structure is required to answer properly

Comment: With that being said, Nick - I suggest you **not** answer until you have all the required details.  The SO community can be a bit rough with inaccurate / incomplete answers.

Answer (score 0):

You query obviously can't work as is since every row only has a single state.
The self-join above is the preferred solution.

But I think is might be a better way to wrap your head around the problem.
We simple select an item from the table if we can find rows that match each
of your subcriteria.

```
SELECT item from table T1
WHERE Exists (Select item from table T2 Where T2.Item = T1.Item 
                                            and T2.state = 'Start'
                                            and T2.Time <= @startTime)
   AND Exists (Select item from table T3 Where T3.Item = T1.Item 
                                        and T3.state = 'Passed'
                                        and T3.Time <= @passTime)
```

I don't know all the nuances of MySql.  Is it smart enough when using Exists to evaluate the Exist subquery for a single row and discard the project.   I often make this explicit by using "Top (1) 1" in my Exists subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way of solving this without some sort of subquery.  An alternative to the answers already given is to use conditional aggregation to count the records for each item which have state `Start` and `Passed`.  Then use this result to filter off item records which do not match both:

```
SELECT
FROM items t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Item,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (State = 'Start'  AND HOUR(time) <= 17) OR
                      (State = 'Passed' AND HOUR(time) <= 21)
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END) AS stateCount
    FROM items
    GROUP BY item
    HAVING stateCount >= 2
) t2
    ON t1.item = t2.item
```

Note that your `time` column does not at all appear to be in an acceptable MySQL format.  It looks like text and you should fix this before trying to use any of the answers given.